# Deserialize list of objects to another collection type

Tags: .net, json, json.net, deserialization

I have some JSON:

```
{
  "id": "e296c8d9-22f6-4326-8630-06d3df9d6375",
  "body": {
    "action": "update",
    "entity": "data",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 470341982
      },
      {
        "id": 470341983
      },
      {
        "id": 470341984
      },

    ]
  }
}
```

And also I have a set of classes:

```
class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("body")]
    public XBody Body { get; set; }
}

class XBody
{
    [JsonProperty("action")]
    public string Action { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("entity")]
    public string Entity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public List<DataItem> DataItems { get; set; }
}

class DataItem
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long ID { get; set; }
}
```

Using Newtonsoft.Json library I do:

```
var myRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

All is ok but I have `List<DataItem>` in the `XBody` object. It is enough for me to have a property of type `List<long>` populated with `DataItem.ID` property values.

Is there a possibility to perform that conversion in the fly without keeping `List<DataItem> DataItems` and having only `List<long> IDs` property instead?

Maybe it it possible to create some additional custom converters using infrastructure of Newtonsoft.Json library?

Comment: Do you wan to keep the other properties, or have only `List<long> IDs`? You could use `var IDs = DataItems.Select(i => i.ID)` after deserialization

Comment: I also need other properties in the XBody, but instead of `List <DataItem> DataItems` it should be `List <long> IDs`

Comment: I suppose that `JsonConverterAttribute` for `List <long> IDs` can help, but I don't know how to realize `ReadJson()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a simple `JsonConverter` class to flatten the `items` object array to a list of longs, thereby eliminating the need for the `DataItem` class.

Here is the code you would need for the converter:

```
class ItemListConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(List<long>));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return JArray.Load(reader)
                     .Children<JObject>()
                     .Select(jo => (long)jo["id"])
                     .ToList();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite 
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use it, change the list property in your `XBody` class to be a `List<long>` instead of a `List<DataItem>` and annotate it with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute like this:

```
class XBody
{
    ...
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ItemListConverter))]
    public List<long> IDs { get; set; }
}
```

Then, when you deserialize, it should work the way you want.

Full demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3DAiEf

Comment: Glad I could help!